# Issue with textarea resize and text wrap when textarea field is inside a table

Tags: jquery, textarea, word-wrap, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

There are many posts on how to disable textarea resizing. I have a reverse problem. In fact two. I need to enable it. It is inside a table td. Here is the simple markup. It is generated dynamically, but thats besides the point (or so I think). Other problem is with textwrap.

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="description_input">
          <input class="descr_text" type="textarea" name="descr_1">
          <input type="file" name="filename"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </form>
```

If I use JqueryUI resizable() widget, it does not work because the text area is dynamically generated and I suspect there are issues with event binding.

The second problem is that I am unable to get word wrap on the text area, it just keeps accepting the input as one long single-line string. I tried a few CSS on the textarea field. Just realized while writing this post that may be I should set CSS on the outer td too?

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
<input class="descr_text" type="textarea" name="descr_1">
```

to:

```
<textarea class="descr_text" name="descr_1"></textarea>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc8tH/)

U can resize it using:

```
textarea{
    height: some px;
    width: some px;
}
```

Comment: How about the textwrap. That is not working... though I can resize it. Must be something basic again.

Comment: try this link for wrapping [textwrap](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_wrap.asp)

Comment: All's fixed and fine. Thanks